# How to create an entity object from an array?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I want to store the data of an entity in the session so that the application doesn't have to fetch it all the time from the database. But I would like to still be able to use it as an entity, so how can I achieve this? For example, if I have this:

```
$user = $session->get('user'); // array('id' => 123, 'username' => 'Foo');
```

How can I hydrate an user entity? I'm looking for something like this:

```
$userEntity = $em->createFromArray($user);

// Later on, I should be able to do stuff like this:

$userEntity->modifySomething();
$em->flush();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Load the User entity when they first login and save it serialized in the session.

```
$session->set('user', serialize($user));
```

When you need to access your user entity, simply do

```
$userEntity = unserialize($session->get('user'));
```

Just remember to update it in the session if the entity gets persisted